# javascript function takes string and returns array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, function

First I have an array that has two strings in it.

```
var Array = ["firstName lastName" , "anotherString"]
```

I would like to create a function that takes in a string as a parameter and returns an array by breaking up the input string into individual words. So the output in this example would be  ["firstName", "lastName"] ?

I know it would look something like this

```
var newFun = function(string) {
     return string[0]    // than do something else 
}
```

Help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: `Array[0].split(" ")` ?

Comment: "*I would like to create a function that...*" — and you got stuck, where?

Comment: Spending a little time learning Javascript will pay off in spades!

Comment: You should never use `Array` as a variable name. Just saying.

Answer (score 2):

So simple, use the `String.prototype.split` method to split strings into array list.

MDN:

> The split() method splits a String object into an array of strings by separating the string into substrings.

```
 return str.split(' ');
```

@Christoph:
You are using some very bad conventions here.

```
var Array
function (string)
```

`Array` is a predefined class in javascript and `string` is pretty close to the predefined class `String`, so just avoid using them completely.

```
var arr;
function (str)
```

**Short Method:** splits a string with multiple words, handles funky strings that `String.prototype.split(' ')` can't handle like `"  firstName  Lastname"` or just `"firstName   Lastname"`. returns an `Array`

```
function smartSplit (str) {
    // .trim() remove spaces surround the word
    // /\s+/ split multiple spaces not just one ' '
    return str.trim().split(/\s+/);
}
```

**Test Case:**

```
  // case: split(' ');
  console.log("   firstName    lastName".split(' ')); 
  // result: ["", "", "", "firstName", "", "", "", "lastName"]

  // case: split(/\s+/)
  console.log("   firstName    lastName".split(/\s+/)); 
  // result: ["", "firstName", "lastName"]

  // case: .trim().split(/\s+/)
  console.log(smartSplit("   firstName    lastName")); 
  // result: ["firstName", "lastName"]
```

**Complete Method:** same as `smartSplit` except for it expects an `Array` as a parameter instead of a `String`

```
function smartSplitAll (strArr) {
  var newArr = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < strArr.length; i++) {
    // expecting string array
    var str = strArr[i].trim();

    // split the string if it has multiple words
    if (str.indexOf(' ') > -1)
        newArr = newArr.concat(str.split(/\s+/));

    else 
        newArr.push(str);
  }

  return newArr;
}

console.log(smartSplitAll(["firstName lastName", "anotherString"]);
// result: ["firstName", "lastName", "anotherString"]
```

Code lives here: http://jsfiddle.net/8xgzkz16/

Comment: Not to mention that it's a bad idea to call a variable `Array` and hand an array to a function and call the parameter `string`...

Comment: `string` is no reserved word, `String` however is;) (Technically it is not, because you CAN use this word as variable name, this however will break some funcitonality)

Answer (score 1):

The index of [0] is actually the first character of the string.

Do this:

```
var myString = "My Name";
var splitResult = myString.split(" ");
```

Will result in:

```
["My", "Name"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var newFun = function(str) {
 return str.split(" "); 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this using the split method from the object `String`

```
var newFun = function(string) {
     return string[0].split(" ");
}
```

Voilà !

Comment: Indeed. The split function will return an array of string splitted according to the character passed in parameter. So if I have a string `"I really love apple"`and split it using the space character `myStr.split(" ")` it will returns this `["I", "really", "love", "apple"]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the string split method:

```
function splitString(input) {
    return input.split(" ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Several comments on your code:

1) the function you are looking for is `String.prototype.split`:

```
var string = "firstName lastName";
string.split(" ");
// returns an array: ["firstName","lastName"]
```

2) don't call your array `Array`. This is a "reserved word"* for the Array prototype! You are overwriting the prototype, if you do so!

3) Keep the naming of your parameters consistent. This way you avoid error like you did in your code. Handing over an array and call the parameter string is a bad idea. `string[0]` returns the first symbol of the string, `array[0]` the first element of your array. Also, name the function appropriately.

Your code should look like this:

```
var array = ["firstName lastName" , "anotherString"];

function returnSplitString(string){
   return string.split(" ");
}

var splitStringArray = returnSplitString(array[0]);
```

`*` In the strict technical sense it is not, because you CAN name your variable that way, however it's a bad idea to do so.

Answer (score 0):

This splitter will take any array with mixed string (strings with spaces and without spaces) and split them in a linear array.

```
var splitter = (array) => {
return array.reduce((acc, value) => {
   return /\s/.test(value) ?  acc.concat(value.trim().split(' ')) : acc.concat(value) ;

}, []);
}


console.log(splitter(["There is proper space", "ThereIsNoSpace"]));
```

will output: 
    `['There', 'is', 'proper', 'space', 'thereisnospace']`